# Required Field Validator are not working

Tags: asp.net, html

I used asp required field  in my code but data in text box  are sending even they are empty when clicking on the button and after they are sending, message of required field appears!! 
 Please help! Thanks in advance...

The source code looks like this

```
<asp:Label ID="LabelUserName" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName" meta:resourcekey="UserName">Nom  :</asp:Label>

<asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" ValidationGroup="val" ></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Entrez your name " ControlToValidate="UserName" ForeColor="Red" ValidationGroup="val">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Here is the code of the button :

```
 <asp:Button  runat="server" Text="Envoyer" ID="Button1" Width="78px" ValidationGroup="val"   />
```

Comment: Let's see the code-behind that handles the button click.

Answer (score 2):

Can't say for sure without seeing the code inside the event handle for your button click, but my guess is you are missing a check to be sure the page is valid.  For example:

```
If (Page.IsValid) Then
    ' do your thing
Else
    'do nothing
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `required` will help you to solve this issue of field validator

eg:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
```